# Using mongoose 5.x to find by condition and groupby foreign key

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to query a collection, and I only want results that meet a createdAt criteria, then I want to group those results by a groupId

I've tried using $match and $group, but I get an error saying my foreignKey (groupId) is undefined

```
Call.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        createdAt: {
            $gte: "2019-04-24T00:00:00.000Z",
            $lt: "2019-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: groupId
    }
}
]).exec().then(result => {

 result.forEach(function (call) {
        console.log(call.createdAt);
    });

return res.status(200).json({
results: result});

});
```

Comment: Try `_id: '$groupId'`